How to add a nav link in the section "My account"
I was trying to add a new link to navbar in my account, I added a new item to navbar beside
Account Settings.
But I am unable to set a link to it using like {{urls.account.cards}}. How i implemented the new navbar item is like below.
Ref: Cornerstone github repo

Edited cornerstone/lang/en.json - Added new object to

"account": {
    "nav": {
        "recently_viewed": "Recently Viewed",
        "settings": "Account Settings",
        "cards": "Cards",
    },
    carditems": {
        "heading" : "Testing Cards",
        "no_items": "The cards you've saved on our site will appear below."
    }
}


Edited cornerstone/templates/components/account/navigation.html - Added new list under Account Settings

<li class="navBar-item {{#if account_page '===' 'carditems'}}is-active{{/if}}">
    <a class="navBar-action" href="{{urls.account.carditems}}">{{lang 'account.nav.cards'}}</a>
</li>


Edited cornerstone/templates/components/common/navigation-menu.html - Added new list under Account Settings

<li class="navPage-subMenu-item">
    <a class="navPage-subMenu-action navPages-action" href="{{urls.account.carditems}}" aria-label="{{lang 'account.nav.cards'}}">{{lang 'account.nav.cards'}}</a>
</li>


Created new file carditems.html at

cornerstone/templates/pages/account/carditems.html


carditems.html

{{#partial "page"}}
<div class="account">
    {{> components/common/breadcrumbs breadcrumbs=breadcrumbs}}
    <h2 class="page-heading">{{lang 'account.carditems.heading' }}</h2>
    {{> components/account/navigation account_page='carditems'}}

    {{#unless customer.recently_viewed_products.items}}
        {{> components/common/alert/alert-info (lang 'account.carditems.no_items')}}
    {{/unless}}
</div>
{{/partial}}
{{> layout/base}}

But I cant get the link to work, so I am not able to show the carditems page
Tried to insert new navbar item and attach link to it.
I was able to add new navbar item but cannot attach link and page to it

You cannot manipulate the Stencil context to add another URL here. And you cannot add new account links. You could, however, create a web page for your new account page and add a direct link to it in the account bar.
And you could add the account navigation to this new page by specifying a custom page template for it, or with a conditional statement inside page.html.
